# Upload images/files to DB with asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I would need some help I have my own Project going on and i would need some help with how to upload images/files to database using entity framework code first

I want to be able to have form with content like title/bodytext etc and  file uploading. I'm pretty new to c# or even web developing. I have a model class with `Byte[]` but when I upload it to db it says null.

And then when I loop through database, I want to display the title, body text and the image I uploaded for each post I did.

Comment: You can upload image and image location(string) save to db.Why save image to Db?

Comment: Have you tried to change the form like this : @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

Comment: Would you edit this to show us what you have tried? Without an attempt, it is likely to be regarded as "too broad" and closed.